# thousand and million formatting for negative numbers (excel/ googlesheets)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formatting

Hello I currently use this formatting to show big numbers as either 1.2M or 20K (instead of 1 200  000 ans 20 000):

[>999999]0.00,,\M;[>999]0.0,\K;0.0,\K

I  have an issue  for negative numbers, I can show -20K but how can I also show -20M?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know whether you can use the logic here, and fiddle with it, as  it seems Excel will only allow 2 conditionals for the formatting. https://superuser.com/questions/100822/custom-format-positive-and-negative-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its not possible.**

What you could do is add a formulae like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/100822/custom-format-positive-and-negative-in-excel)

or you could use conditional formatting along with multiple formats like [this](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010227_Handling_Negative_Numbers_in_a_Complex_Custom_Format.html)