# Excel number format to k or m

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a custom format in Excel to display the numbers in Excel column to show k for thousands and M for million, or as normal number if below 10,000. The cells in that column can have both negative and positive values.

I tried the custom format below, but it is not giving correct results.

```
[<-999000]-0,, \M;[<-1000]-0, K;#,##0
```

what is the correct format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275247/format-numbers-in-thousands-k-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

After last one hour of playing around what I found is having multiple condition with positive and negative it not possible to my knowledge

Refer this stackoverflow question

[thousand and million formatting for negative numbers (excel/ googlesheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872256/thousand-and-million-formatting-for-negative-numbers-excel-googlesheets)

However you could still try different way using formula

https://superuser.com/questions/100822/custom-format-positive-and-negative-in-excel

Comment: but it will only display K, how to display M for values in millions, also how to handle the negative as well as positive to show K and M based on value entered in the cell.

Comment: Sure, give me moment I will try to add, I just added for an idea